# Creating a simple dictionary using WordNet

Tags: php, mysql, wordnet

I'm installing WordNet in MySQL from http://www.semantilog.org/wn2sql.html

I'd like to display the data in the same way as Princeton's webpage: http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=car

How would I query the database to do that? I'm using PHP.

Comment: @hakre I think a good way to start is the way princeton does it but. I don't need to display Sysnet (semantic relations, etc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I gather from the documentation on the website, it seems you need to query three tables.

First you query the **word** table in order to get it's *wordno*, a unique number each word has. It would look something like this.

```
//assuming you've connected to your MySQL db
$word=$_GET['s']; //This variable stores the value given through url
if (ctype_alpha($word)){ // If it's alphabetical
  $word_clean=mysql_real_escape_string($word); //Sanitize it for MySQL
}else{
  //Not a valid word, error handle
  exit();
}
$query='SELECT wordno FROM word WHERE lemma=`$word_clean` LIMIT 1';
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

Next, we need to query the **sense** table in order to get the *synsetno*, which'll output the different senses of the word. Ex: can (noun) and can (verb), each have a unique number which is the *synsetno*

The MySQL query will be something along the lines of:

```
$query='SELECT synsetno FROM sense WHERE wordno=`$wordno`';
```

For each result you get from that query, you'll have to query the **synset** table to get the *definition* of each sense. Can (noun) and can (verb) have different definitions. The query for each *synsetno*.

```
$query='SELECT definition FROM synset WHERE synsetno=`$synset`';
```

And presto! You have yourself a pretty cool dictionary. It is a pain on the CPU, however, to have to query three tables, each with a ton of records.

Comment: This is enough to get me started. Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me how to get example sentences for a word?

Comment: you can use a join `SELECT * FROM word JOIN sense on sense.wordno = word.wordno JOIN synset on sense.synsetno = synset.synsetno WHERE word.lemma LIKE 'wheel' ORDER BY `sense`.`tagcnt` DESC`